# How to get an Item value in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following challenge. I want to get the name of the Items display on the `gridview` from the side behind...

Pass this name as a parameter to get the count of responses for the item. This response count will be displayed on a label controls in the template fields created.

Below is my code sample.

```
// Create an instance of the LogicLayer
LogicLayer mySurvey = new LogicLayer();
DataLayer getResponseCount = new DataLayer();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvDepartments.DataSource = mySurvey.SelectDepartment();
    gvDepartments.DataBind();
    gvDepartments.Visible = true;

    // Declare a counter variable
    int dID = 0;
    string responses;
    string deptName;
    //string responseR;
    // Iterate though the gridView to get Dept names and response count values
    foreach (GridViewRow dept in gvDepartments.Rows) 
    {
        //Label respCount = (Label)dept.FindControl("lblResponse").Text
        // the actual way to get your row index
        int rowIndex = dept.RowIndex;
        Label respCount = (Label)gvDepartments.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lblResponses");
        responses = respCount.Text.ToString();
        deptName = dept.Cells[rowIndex].ToString(); // Get the department name on the gridview
        // get the responseCount for each of the departments and Map to Labels
        responses = getResponseCount.ResponseCount(deptName);
        dID++;
    }
}
```

This is the pictural view of my grid.

[image]

Comment: possibly better calculate `respCount` from `mySurvey.SelectDepartment()` instead of from grid

Comment: You certainly don't understand my question. The method mySurvey.SelectDepartment() returns a DataSet which is bounded to the GridView. I need the names of the Bounded Departments to get the count of responses for that department.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
GridViewRow row = gvDepartments.Rows[rowIndex];

String value = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString(); // I assume 2 is the column index of response you could use `FindControl` method for template fields
```

Answer (score 1):

After much search to get solution to my question above. I used the RowDataBound event as seen below

```
// Create an instance of the LogicLayer
LogicLayer mySurvey = new LogicLayer();
DataLayer getResponseCount = new DataLayer();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvDepartments.DataSource = mySurvey.SelectDepartment();
    gvDepartments.DataBind();
    gvDepartments.Visible = true;
}
protected void gvDepartments_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Declare a counter variable
    int dID = 0;
    string responses;
    string deptName;
    //string responseR;

    // Iterate though the gridView to get Dept names and response count values

    foreach (GridViewRow dept in gvDepartments.Rows)
    {
        //Label respCount = (Label)dept.FindControl("lblResponse").Text
        // the actual way to get your row index
        int rowIndex = dept.RowIndex;
        Label respCount = (Label)gvDepartments.Rows[dID].FindControl("lblResponses");
        responses = respCount.Text.ToString();
        // dept.Cells[rowIndex].ToString();  Get the department name on the gridview
        **deptName = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();**

        // get the responseCount for each of the departments and Map to Labels
        responses = getResponseCount.ResponseCount(deptName);

        dID++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fault in finding the `deptName`. You have to use `Cell Index` instead of `rowIndex`. `rowIndex` may grow based on the number of rows. Since the cells or 0 based indexed, so you can find the `deptName` at index "1", which will be constant unless the column position is changed.
You can get the value of `deptName` as following

```
deptName = dept.Cells[1].ToString();
```